# Styling buttons for Microsoft Outlook

Tags: css, outlook

I am currently setting up my first newsletter i Mailchimp. After checking the newsletter in different email clients I can see that my "buttons" does not look right in Outlook.
Below is my code for the button;

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" bgcolor="#96d1eb" 
style="color: #ffffff; 
font-size: 13px; 
border-radius: 5px;
display: block; 
padding-right: 22px; 
padding-left: 22px; 
padding-bottom: 8px; 
padding-top: 8px; 
line-height: 22px; 
vertical-align: middle;" 
mc:edit="2">
<!--[if !mso]><!--><span style=" font-weight: normal;"><!--<![endif]-->
<a href="#" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 13px;
text-decoration: none; line-height: 20px;" class="hover">Shop Now</a>
<!--[if !mso]><!--></span><!--<![endif]-->
</td>
```

This gives me the following result in most email clients;

[image]

Although when i look in Outlook the text is not vertical centered and without rounded corners;

[image]

How can i make the button in Outlook look the same as in the other email clients?

Answer (score 0):

...I would suggest setting the line-height the same as the font-size and playing with the link's padding to get the same result. I am certain that this is causing the issue.